# Codeigniter Limit not working

Tags: codeigniter, model, limit

I'm nearly reaching rage mode!

Can anyone help me with this??

I setted a limit on a CodeIgniter Model so I can only that set of results. Why is it not working? The records are displaying correctly on function call, but I'm getting more than how it's supposed to

```
 $this->CI->dbClient->select('id,title,description,url,date,id_first_image')
                                   ->from('posts')
                                   ->where('deleted',"0")
                                   ->where('date >',$date)
                                   //Neither does work here!
                                   ->order_by('date','asc')
                                   ->limit(5);

       $query =     $this->CI->dbClient->get();       
       return $query->result();
```

Comment: Try putting $str=$this->db->last_query(); print($str); die; after your query runs and see what it's returning

Comment: @RickCalder You comment helped me solving the issue. Thank you! Please post a formal answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Use `db`

Use `db` for the Active Record class.

```
$this->db->select('id, title, description, url, date, id_first_image')
                               ->from('posts')
                               ->where('deleted', "0")
                               ->where('date >', $date)
                               ->order_by('date', 'asc')
                               ->limit(5);

$query = $this->db->get();       
return $query->result();
```

### 2. `$data` is Valid

Ensure that `$data` is a valid MySQL date (or whatever your underlying database technology might be).

Comment: I can't use db as I'm overwriting db rules with dbClass